# Value of csrftoken in document.cookie is different from csrftoken in Cookies

Tags: ajax, django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am using django rest framework. I have Ember frontend. Here, when I am getting the csrftoken from Cookies.get("csrftoken"), its different from the csrftoken I see in the browser cookies.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

See that the csrftoken in Cookie is different from X-CSRFToken(which is set by Cookies.get("csrftoken")).

Why are they different? I need both of them to be same. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `X-CSRFToken` manually before sending request. Django docs contains good example about that:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax

It's about JQuery, but you should grasp the idea:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Idea is the following: server send you your csrf-token in cookies, your client read cookies and set token in the header. Server read requests headers, see good `X-CSRFToken` and know, that request is valid.

Comment: Yeah. That I know. That is what I told. After setting the X-CSRFToken, the csrf is different from what I see in cookies.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't tell that you set your csrf-token into `X-CSRFToken` header. Only that you read it from cookies and this is different from `X-CSRFToken` value, which Ember send. Maybe i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.10.To protect against BREACH attacks, the CSRF protection mechanism now changes the form token value on every request (while keeping an invariant secret which can be used to validate the different tokens).
Maybe your Django version is 1.10[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#whats-new-1-10)